# React Router w/ URL params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router and have a route path `taskSupport/:advertiserId`
with params but when I try to go to the link, `http://localhost:8080/taskSupport/advertiserId`, I get a bunch of 404 (Not found) errors for all my css files and my client.min.js file. 
Anyone know what's going on? Sorry I'm a react noob... 
Any help will be much appreciated!

```
<Route path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={Layout}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="about" component={About}></Route>
    <Route path="referral" component={Referral}></Route>
    <Route path="taskSupport(/:advertiserId)" name="taskSupport" component={TaskSupport}></Route>
    <Route path="faq" component={Faq}></Route>
    <Route path="faq-plain" component={FaqPlain}></Route>
</Route>
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>BitMaker</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/bitmaker.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/faq.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/error404.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/taskSupport.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        appHtml
    </div>
    <script src="client.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add the html that pulls in the css and js files? You could be using relative links which would try to obtain them from "/taskSupport/:advertiserID/filename.ext" instead of from the root of the domain. Also try using this route path for taskSupport instead: "taskSupport/:advertiserId", without the parenthesis.

Comment: The parenthesis just make the advertiserId param optional. I will add my html file

Comment: Oh okay so yes you are using relative links for your resources, which tries to grab them from whichever location you're at. To pull them from the root, have your reference links start with a '/' like so: '/css/stylesheet.css' and '/client.min.js'.

Comment: Ahh I see awesome it worked! thanks so much!!

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the HTML file with react projects. If you want to include css files in your HTML then use an import statement in your react code so you dont have to deal with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relative links issue.

You were using relative links which would try to obtain them from "/taskSupport/:advertiserID/filename.ext" instead of from the root of the domain.

To pull them from the root, have your reference links start with a forward slash '/' **'/css/stylesheet.css'** and **'/client.min.js'**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
```

and

```
<script src="/client.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your links to react routes should look like this.

`<Link to="/taskSupport/adID123"></Link>`

you'll need to import the link component from react-router like this.

`import { Link } from 'react-router'`

I also think you want your route set up like this

`<Route path="/taskSupport/(:advertiserId)" name="taskSupport" component={TaskSupport}></Route>`

If the forward slash is not looked for after taskSupport then the regex is pretty much this,

`<Route path="taskSupport*(/:advertiserId)" name="taskSupport" component={TaskSupport}></Route>`

Since taskSupport* will match taskSupport/abc123/ the optional part will never be matched.

If you change the route to this

`<Route path="/taskSupport/(:advertiserId)" name="taskSupport" component={TaskSupport}></Route>`

Then the regex knows when to end it's match and start looking for an advertiserId

Also when you include local CSS in your project you should use an import inside react and not modify your HTML file.

`import './index.css';`

Answer (score -1):

You're using "HTML5 Mode" style routes (as opposed to # routes) for your single page app

Without knowing more about your project and its dependencies, you can try to set a `<base>` in your HTML head, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This actually worked in that the component loaded by going to the link: `http://localhost:8080/taskSupport/advertiserId` 
but none of the css files loaded... Is the way I have my routing and html file set up bad practice? Is there a more preferred and easier way to organize my routing? If that makes sense... haha

Comment: I think this combined with @Michael Lyons answer is what you're looking for, where the `<base>` addressed one issue, and the absolute CSS paths (add a leading `/` to your CSS files) will likely fix your CSS loading